# PrimeNG table not filtering null Values properly

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, primeng

I'm getting problems when I try to filter null values of a row in Primeng's p-table. I'm trying this way but it doesn't filter null values, just values that are not null...

html:

```
<p-table #st [value]="employees">
  <ng-template pTemplate="header">
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Office</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of employeeCols" [ngSwitch]="col.field" [class]="'stickyFilter'">
        <p-multiSelect *ngSwitchCase="'officeId'" [options]="officeFilter" defaultLabel="Todas"
          (onChange)="st.filter($event.value, col.field,'in')">
        </p-multiSelect>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-emp>
    <tr>
      <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
      <td>{{emp.age}}</td>
      <td>{{emp.office}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

typescript file:

```
officeFilter: SelectItem[] = [];
employeeCols: any[];
employees: any[] = [];

constructor(){
  
  this.employees = [{ name: 'jack', age: 33, officeId: 1 }, { name: 'Marge', age: 24, officeId: 2 }, 
     { name: 'Ryan', age: 33, officeId: null }];
  
  this.officeFilter = [{ label: 'Luisiana', value: 1 }, { label: 'Montana', value: 2 }, { label: 'Not 
     assigned', value: null }]
  
  this.employeeCols = [  
    { field: 'name', header: 'Name' },
    { field: 'age', header: 'Age' },
    { field: 'officeId', header: 'Office' }
  ];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The last element of `this.employees` has an office key, instead of officeId, is that on purpose?

Comment: My bad, it's a mistake that i wrote while copy-pasting...

Comment: [See this](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/003d8eb55ffa4d121300d9b9875aa809b69ad1d3/src/app/components/table/table.ts#L1264). `null` has a special value in p-table as it deletes the filter from the array. You should use something else (like 0 or -1).

Comment: @ferikeem Sure! But the point is that I am receiving info from database and I would like to show that cell as an empty cell... I have found out that if I change null value with an ' ' either on the employees array and filter I can filter it but I don't think this is a good practice hahaha.

Comment: Oh, I see. Empty string might be your best option then. You (probably) won't find a better practice, as `null` is preserved for clearing the filtering. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯